# Redimensionar imagens passando os valores pela url

Tags: php, javascript

No meu site de downloads de programas, tem imagens de diversos tamanhos, como por exemplo: para cada programa tem uma imagem (*thumbnail*), uma imagem grande e as screenshots.

Só que quero tornar as imagens tudo do mesmo tamanho e pela url passar o tamanho que quero da imagem. Algo como: `uploads/imagens/imagen-teste.jpg?w=500&h=500`. Caso eu queira a mesma imagem em outro tamanho, só passaria o valor pela url, ficando assim: `uploads/imagens/imagen-teste.jpg?w=100&h=100`.

Como posso fazer isso? Ou existe algum plugin que faça isso?

Comment: caso você já tenha o script, e use uma função que aceite parâmetros externos, pode-se chamar a função da seguinte maneira em sua página php

`function alteraDimensoes(width, height)`
 ficaria assim: `function alteraDimensoes(<?= img["width"] ?>,<?= img["height"] ?>)`

Mas lembre-se de usar o GET

Answer (score 3):

Olá.

Pra passar pela URL, você precisaria solicitar um get passando o width e height.

Você pode fazer isso facilmente com PHP.

```
<?php

//Parametros obtidos via Get
$width = $_GET('WIDTH');
$height = $_GET('HEIGHT');

//URL da imagem
$url = 'img/foto.jpg';

//pega a imagem para redimensionar com base na URL
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($url);

//pega a largura e altura original da imagem
$orig_width = imagesx($image);
$orig_height = imagesy($image);

//Gera a nova imagem e redimensiona com base nos valores passados
$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
imagecopyresized($new_image, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $orig_width, $orig_height);

//Exibe a imagem
imagejpeg($new_image);
?>
```

para mais informações: https://blog.countableset.com/2012/01/03/gd-slash-php-image-resize-based-on-width/